# Two geom_line and geom_point on same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `df` which looks like this

```
    > dput(head(df))
    structure(list(Percent = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Test = c(4, 2, 3, 
    5, 2), Train = c(10, 12, 10, 13, 15)), .Names = c("Percent", 
    "Test", "Train"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like this

```
Percent    Test    Train
1          4       10
2          2       12
3          3       10
4          5       13
5          2       15
```

How can I plot `Test` and `Train` into a two lines with `ggplot` ?

I've got something like this right now

```
ggplot(dfk, aes(x = Percent, y = Test)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

I also want to add `Train` points and line connected onto the plot and have them a different color with labels in a legend. I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways, either add layers or restructure your data beforehand.

Adding layers:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Percent)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Test), colour = "red") + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Train), colour = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Train), colour = "blue")
```

Restructure your data:

```
# df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, key = type, value = value, -Percent) # Old way
df2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -Percent, names_to = "type", values_to = "value") # New way

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Percent, y = value, colour = type)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line()
```

Option 2 is generally preferred because it plays to `ggplot2`'s strengths and elegance.